# Convert Access TRANSFORM/PIVOT query to SQL Server with multiple table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Need to convert this query for sql server. I tried few examples but they didn't work for me.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY) AS SumOfORDER_QTY
SELECT CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER LEFT JOIN CUST_ORDER_LINE ON CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID
WHERE (((CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID) Is Not Null) AND ((CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS) In ('F','R')))
GROUP BY CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID
PIVOT CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY,CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID,CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS as STATUS
 FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER_LINE ON CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID ) as s
PIVOT
(
SUM(CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY)
FOR [STATUS] IN (F,R) ) as pvt           ---I've tried this example but getting an error.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: The column prefix 'CUST_ORDER_LINE' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: Is there a table named `CUST_ORDER_LINE` or is it `CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE`? Please post the table schemas.

Comment: 2 tables used in this query. "CUST_ORDER_LINE " and "CUSTOMER_ORDER". There is no CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE table.

Comment: Remove the `CUST_ORDER_LINE.` from the `SUM()` function in the `PIVOT`. The `PIVOT` is referencing the select referenced as `s`.